# How to assign local variable to normal variables in Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to calculate my h1 tag top position on scrolling. I found this code in net, It seems working for me. But, what is the problem is that however I print the value inside the scroll function I can get the value. But, when I assign that value to my variable It always shows 0. I don't know why it is happening?

```
var my_offset = 0;
$(window).scroll(function() {
  var $h1 = $("h1");
  var window_offset = $h1.offset().top - $(window).scrollTop();
  my_offset = window_offset;
});
console.log(my_offset);
```

Comment: Are you sure the function is triggering? Put an alert() call in it to check.

Answer (score 3):

You need to put the `console.log` line *inside* the scroll handler, otherwise it is only run once on load of the page when the value is `0`. You should also remove the `var` in the `scroll` event handler if you want to retain the scope of the `my_offset` variable. Try this:

```
var my_offset = 0;
$(window).scroll(function() {
    my_offset = $("h1").offset().top - $(window).scrollTop();
    console.log(my_offset);
});
```

[**Working example**](https://jsfiddle.net/qhcabjo0/)

Comment: I want the offset value outside of the scroll function.

Comment: It is available outside of the scroll function. You just need to retrieve the value *after* the scroll has been used to set the value.